# Join 2 table in Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, eloquent

I have 2 tables in my database which is :-

`pams_project` table has table structure `project_name`, `dev_id`(FK) 
`pams_developer` table has table structure `developer_name`, `id`(PK)

Now, I create 2 model and make relationship between this 2 tables:-

`Project.php` model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Developer;

class Project extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'pams_project';
    protected $primaryKey = 'project_id';


    public function developer()
    {

        return $this->belongsTo(Developer::class,'dev_id','id');

    }
}
```

`Developer.php` model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Project;

class Developer extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = 'pams_developer';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    public function projects()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Project::class,'dev_id','id');


    }
}
```

Now, I face a problem, I want to retrieve the developer_name and project_name from this 2 model like as the SQL below :-

```
 SELECT D.developer_name , P.project_name
 FROM pams_developer AS D
 JOIN pams_project AS P
 ON P.dev_id = D.id
 GROUP BY D.developer_name
```

But I have no idea how to write in this 2 model to retrieve the data from my controllers.
Any suggestion or solution is appreaciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should check laravel documentation on how to use eloquent relationships (and eager loading relationship):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships

For your (a bit unclear) example would be:

```
$developers = App\Developer::with('projects')->get();

foreach($developers as $developer) {
    echo $developer->developer_name;

    foreach($developer->projects as $project) {
        echo $project->project_name;
}
```

Comment: There is a missing `'` in the first line after `('projects`.

Comment: Thanks your comments. But may i ask your code is put in the controller right ?